# reg should start with $, from then on match every full word seperated with a comma

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to create a regex for this this:

> .domain.com$object-subrequest,third-party,domain=domain.com|domain2.com|domain3.com|domain4.com

The best result would be to match it into a result like this:

```
- object-subrequest
- third-party
- domain
-- domain.com
-- domain2.com
-- domain3.com
-- domain4.com
```

But I don't know if that's even possible. A result like this would be okay as well:

```
- object-subrequest
- third-party
- domain
```

And then another regex to filter out all domains like this:

```
-- domain.com
-- domain2.com
-- domain3.com
-- domain4.com
```

So far I've only been able to come up wiht this:
https://regex101.com/r/wP8cY7/1

```
/(script|image|stylesheet|object|xmlhttprequest|subdocument|document|elemhide|other|third-party|domain|sitekey|match-case|collapse|donottrack),*/g
```

As you can see, this matches everything containing one of the words, I only need everything after the `$`.
I use only Javascript (no jQuery).

Comment: I don't see how the regex you listed has anything to do with the problem you're trying to solve. They seem to be completely unrelated. I see words in the regex like `stylesheet` and `elemhide` and `donottrack`. None of these appear in your sample string. What is the connection between this regex and the string you are trying to parse?

Comment: My example is part of it. All those words are possible matches. In my example I only used `object-subrequest`, `third-party` and `domain`. In the regex101 you'll see the problem with the regex I've got so far, but that regex isn't working the way I want it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get rid of everything before the `$` in some other way, this regexp is near what you want I think:

```
/[$,](script|image|stylesheet|object|xmlhttprequest|subdocument|document|elemhide|other|third-party|domain|sitekey|match-case|collapse|donottrack)/gi
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the input `x` at dollar signs and commas; take all components of the first component except for the first component of the first component.  Then split that by equal and or signs:

```
s <- strsplit(x, "[$,]")[[1]][-1]
strsplit(s, "[=|]")
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] "object-subrequest"

[[2]]
[1] "third-party"

[[3]]
[1] "domain"      "domain.com"  "domain2.com" "domain3.com" "domain4.com"
```

**Note:** We used this as the input `x`:

```
x <- ".domain.com$object-subrequest,third-party,domain=domain.com|domain2.com|domain3.com|domain4.com"
```

Comment: strsplit doesn't look like a javascript function. I was hoping for a regex instead of splitting the string.

Comment: sorry, not sure why this question came up on my list of R questions.